# Deploying Meteor to Heroku with Git

Tags: git, heroku, meteor

I was following the instructions found [here](http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.ca/2013/05/how-to-deploy-meteor-on-heroku-with.html), and I got through the first 8 steps no problem, but this one I don't understand:

> Add the Heroku Git repository as another remote to your git repository and push the code to that remote. The application will be automatically deployed and becomes accesible on .herokuapp.com
> $ git push heroku master

I tried just typing in git push heroku master but that yeilded:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

And now I'm not sure what to do. I feel like I need to configure git to somehow know more about my heroku app or something, but I'm really dealing with stuff I don't understand.

Part of me wants to sit down and learn about git all afternoon, hoping to figure it out, but the other part just wants to deploy my Meteor app!

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix it?

#### EDIT

I've got a new problem now. I ran heroku create, and now when I try running git push heroku master I get

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'an.ip.add.ress' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I still have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like you might need set your git up with `git init`

Comment: You need to run `git push` (and all other `git` commands) from inside the project directory. Were you in a different directory when you ran this command?

Comment: @Akshat, git init did change the error I got, edited the original post with new info.

Comment: @georgebrock, I am in the project directory. Edited the original post with an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added your computers SSH-key to your Heroku-account?

This is how you generate/get the key: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

This is where you add it (when you're logged in to your Heroku-account): https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

---

Though I would probably start by learning a bit more git before getting started with Heroku if I was you. This is a great place for learning git: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control